# AV Player not working in a container view Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, swift5

I am trying to get a video to play within a container view controller. I would like the video to play only within the container view but have the option to full screen it while playing.

[image]

I have a piece of code that can play a video with the screen automatically going full screen using an ‘off container’ button but, I cannot get the video to play within the container. Also, I am unaware of how to use the play button showing on the container view in my image above. The AV Player controller is embedded in the container.

Code below:

```
@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SampleVideo", ofType: "mp4") {
        let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let videoPlayer = PlayerViewController()
        videoPlayer.player = video

        present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
            video.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Is that real code? If so what is PlayerViewController? Is it similar to AVPlayerViewController? Also your code just does a `present`. Where is the code that tries to show the video in a “container”? What you are doing makes no reference to an existing child view controller.

Comment: Hi,

1) Yes it's real code.
2) PlayerViewController() is the class name assigned to AVPlayerViewController Object.
3) Yes, so what i was trying to say is that I can get a video to play using the present method, but I do not know how to get it to play within a container (let's call if 'containerOne') that is in another view controller.

Hope this is a bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

No longer an issue. I found out I should have been using AV Player Layer. Now I have the video playing in a UIImageView and is doing what I needed.